# Is it possible to sort a numeric multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, numeric

```
<?php
$multi = array(
            9,10
            array(5,4),
            array(6,7),
            array(3,2),
            array(8,1)
);

echo "<center>values in Array</center>";

for ($row = 0; $row < 4; $row++) {
    for ($col = 0; $col < 2; $col++) {        
         echo "<center>".$multi[$row][$col]."</center>"."<br>";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: This code is not syntactically correct. Error at line #4. Shouldn't the values 9 and 10 be in another `array()` statement as well?

Comment: yup i know its error but i want to sort that kind of numeric array.

Comment: a numeric array which has multidimensional numeric array and separate numeric values without array.  i want to sort this.